# how to make PC speaker to beep in Adobe Air?

Tags: flash, air

can I make my pc speakers to beep in Adobe Air. As we have beep API in C. when this API is called, PC speakers play a beep. Is there any API in Adobe Air which does the same thing. Thanks

Comment: you can generate beeps easily enough. i have a tut here: http://blog.leeburrows.com/2011/03/beep-and-other-sounds-part1/

Comment: this type need external speaker to play. rather than pc speakers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no built-in support for that but you can write a [native extension](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html).